# need to get recursive list of files using mac command line

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, filelist

I need to get the contents of a folder via mac console window
and put into a text file via >output.txt:

existing structure looks like:

```
folder/index.html
folder/images/backpack.png
folder/shared/bootstrap/fonts/helvertica.eot
folder/css/fonts/helverticabold.eot
folder/shared/css/astyle.css
folder/js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js",
folder/js/libs/jquery.tipsy.js
folder/js/libs/raphael.js
```

what I want looks would look like this (the folder is missing):

```
index.html
images/backpack.png
shared/bootstrap/fonts/helvertica.eot
css/fonts/helverticabold.eot
shared/css/astyle.css
js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js
js/libs/jquery.tipsy.js
js/libs/raphael.js
```

No  css/fonts or js/libs or css folders listed
i.e. no folders….. and no formatting like

/folder/shared/css/astyle.css Or
./folder/shared/css/astyle.css

even better would be  with parens and commas:

```
“index.html”,
“images/backpack.png”,
“shared/bootstrap/fonts/helvertica.eot”,
“css/fonts/helverticabold.eot”,
“shared/css/astyle.css”,
“js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js”,
“js/libs/jquery.tipsy.js”,
“js/libs/raphael.js”
```

As I want to make a json document. Is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: I am confused, why does `ls -R` not work for you? It already does not list the containing folder. If you really need the quotes and commas, you can pipe the output of ls to sed: `ls <dir> | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/",/' > filename`

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of task that `find` is good at:

```
% find folder -type f | sed -e 's,folder/,",' -e 's/$/",/'
```

You *might* be able to adjust the `'s,folder/,",'` substitution by, say

```
(cd folder; find . -type f) | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1",/'
```

Further refinements are an exercise for the reader!

Comment: this does it! but it has a "./" at the start- any way to get rid of it

Comment: i am using (cd folder; find . -type f) | sed 's/\(.*\)/"\1",/'

Comment: Well, since you know that the resulting line will begin with `./`, you can match that in the regular expression, with `'s|^\./(.*)|"\1",|'`